# Error test connect DHCP Kea / ISC DHCPDISCOVER PACKET_NAK_0001

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, dhcp

DHCP сервер находится в другой сети. В своей сети я поднял вирт.машину Linux, там два интерфейса.

Выполняю следующее:

```
dhcrelay ip_dhcp -i имя_пустого_интерфейса
dhclient -v имя_пустого_интерфейса -s ip_dhcp
```

Log Kea выдаёт ошибку:

```
ERROR [kea-dhcp4.bad-packets/26218] DHCP4_PACKET_NAK_0001 [hwtype=1 
<MAC>], cid=[no info], tid=0x23acf436: failed to select a subnet for 
incoming packet, src 172.100.100.100, type DHCPDISCOVER
```

Исправить пока не удалось :(

Пример конфига Kea:

```
{
"command": "config-set",
"service": [
    "dhcp4"
],
"arguments": {
    "Dhcp4": {
        "option-def": [
            {
                "name": "configRevision",
                "code": 254,
                "type": "string",
                "space": "dhcp4"
            }
        ],
        "interfaces-config": {
            "interfaces": [
                "*"
            ],
            "dhcp-socket-type": "udp"
        },
        "control-socket": {
            "socket-type": "unix",
            "socket-name": "/tmp/kea-dhcp4-ctrl.sock"
        },
        "lease-database": {
            "type": "postgresql",
            "host": "host",
            "name": "name",
            "user": "name",
            "password": "pass",
            "port": 5432,
            "lfc-interval": 600
        },
        "expired-leases-processing": {
            "reclaim-timer-wait-time": 10,
            "flush-reclaimed-timer-wait-time": 25,
            "hold-reclaimed-time": 3600,
            "max-reclaim-leases": 100,
            "max-reclaim-time": 250,
            "unwarned-reclaim-cycles": 5
        },
        "valid-lifetime": 3600,
        "authoritative": true,
        "hooks-libraries": [
            {
                "library": "/usr/local/lib/hooks/libdhcp_lease_cmds.so"
            },
            {
                "library": "/usr/local/lib/hooks/libdhcp_stat_cmds.so"
            }
        ],
        "option-data": [
            {
                "name": "configRevision",
                "code": 254,
                "data": "1",
                "always-send": false
            },
            {
                "name": "domain-name-servers",
                "data": "<IP>, <IP>",
                "always-send": true
            },
            {
                "name": "time-servers",
                "data": "<IP>",
                "always-send": true
            },
            {
                "name": "ntp-servers",
                "data": "<IP>",
                "always-send": true
            },
            {
                "name": "domain-name",
                "data": "<DOMAIN>",
                "always-send": true
            },
            {
                "name": "dhcp-server-identifier",
                "data": "<IP>"
            }
        ],
        "shared-networks": [
            {
                "name": "Zone 1",
                "relay": {
                    "ip-addresses": [
                        "172.100.100.100",
                        "<IP>",
                        "<IP>",
                        "<IP>"
                    ]
                },
                "option-data": [],
                "subnet4": [
                    {
                        "id": 1314,
                        "subnet": "172.100.100.99/23",
                        "option-data": [
                            {
                                "name": "routers",
                                "data": "172.100.100.100"
                            }
                        ],
                        "pools": [
                            {
                                "pool": "172.100.100.130-172.100.100.254",
                                "client-class": "UNKNOWN"
                            }
                        ],
                        "valid-lifetime": 86400,
                        "reservations": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```